# Converting the argument name of a function into string

Tags: r

I have developed a function which will take a list of files and will do some statistical tests and will generate a excel file. In the last line of function (return object) I want the function will return a excel file with same names as input file names. In my example it will give list_file.xlsx. IF I enter another file let's say tslist_file it should automatically return tslist_file.xlsx. The function is properly working. Suggest me how I code last line of the function so that I can generalise it.

```
 newey<-function(list_files){
tsmom<-do.call(cbind,lapply(list_files,function(x) read_excel(x)[,2]))
tsmom<-xts(tsmom[,1:5],order.by = seq(as.Date("2005-02-01"),length=183,by="months")-1)
names(tsmom)<-c("tsmom121","tsmom123","tsmom126","tsmom129","tsmom1212")
## newey west
newey_west<-function(x){
  model<-lm(x~1)
  newey_west<-coeftest(model,vcov=NeweyWest(model,verbose=T))
  newey_west[c(1,3,4)]
}

## running newey west 
cs_nw_full<-do.call(cbind,lapply(tsmom,newey_west))
library(gtools)
p_values<-cs_nw_full[3,]
cs_nw_full[2,]<-paste0(cs_nw_full[2,],stars.pval(p_values))
write.xlsx(cs_nw_full,"list_file.xlsx")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```r
write.xlsx(cs_nw_full, paste0(eval(substitute(list_files)), ".xlsx"))
```

**Edit:**
@jeetkamal is absolutely right - you need to use

```r
write.xlsx(cs_nw_full, paste0(deparse(substitute(list_files)), ".xlsx"))
```

here.

I apologize for the mistake. `eval` wold only work if `list_files` was e.g. the name of a file, not a list object.

Comment: this is generating following error. Error in .jnew("java/io/File", file) : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (type == "xls") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (type == "xlsx") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @sim235 try write.xlsx(cs_nw_full, paste0(deparse(substitute(list_files)), ".xlsx"))